# How to access iCloud Calendar Using PHP?

Tags: php, api

i want to develop an PHP Script, where users can create an event in the iCloud Calanders directly.

Now i would like to sync these events with the iCloud Calendars.

Is that possible?

Is there any API or Docomentation.

Thanks

Comment: You have received the answer "no" on another forum.
Before asking again, please read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe you could use caldav. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/94150